# Formula question before my eyes permanently cross

Tags: formula-field

I have a picklist field that has the value of either "A" or "B"

If it is A, I need to take the value of a number field ("d") and based on the number ranges within that field, set the formula field to a tier 1 through 5.
If it is B, I need to take the value of a number field ("c") and based on number ranges within that field, set the formula field to a tier 1 through 5.

I've tried variations of the following, but all of them show errors of one kind or another.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
AND( ISPICKVAL(Industry , "A")),

IF(d >= 201 , "Tier 1", 
IF(d >= 151, "Tier 2", 
IF(d >= 101, "Tier 3",  
IF(d >= 51, "Tier 4", 
IF(d >= 1 , "Tier 5", 
NULL)))))),

OR(
AND( ISPICKVAL(Industry , "B")),

IF(c >= 100000, "Tier 5",  
IF(c>= 40000, "Tier 4",  
IF(c>= 20000 , "Tier 3",  
IF(c>= 10000, "Tier 2",   
IF(c<= 9999 , "Tier 1", 

NULL)))))
)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I did try this variation, (and I also put in yours with the correct fields just in case) but still had this error: Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `CASE`. It's [less compile sized](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006tbI) than `IF`

```
CASE( TestPickList__c , "A",  
    IF(d >= 201 , "Tier 1", 
IF(d >= 151, "Tier 2", 
IF(d >= 101, "Tier 3",  
IF(d >= 51, "Tier 4", 
IF(d >= 1 , "Tier 5", 
NULL)))))
, "B",
    IF(c >= 100000, "Tier 5",  
IF(c>= 40000, "Tier 4",  
IF(c>= 20000 , "Tier 3",  
IF(c>= 10000, "Tier 2",   
IF(c<= 9999 , "Tier 1", 

NULL))))) ,"")
```

Comment: Glad to help you! Play around `CASE`, it's very easy to manage(in a readable way) a formula

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of AND and OR seems not correct. What about this (untested):

```
IF( ISPICKVAL(Industry , "A"),

IF(d >= 201 , "Tier 1", 
IF(d >= 151, "Tier 2", 
IF(d >= 101, "Tier 3",
IF(d >= 51, "Tier 4", 
IF(d >= 1 , "Tier 5", 
""))))),

IF(ISPICKVAL(Industry , "B"),

IF(c >= 100000, "Tier 5",
IF(c>= 40000, "Tier 4",
IF(c>= 20000 , "Tier 3",
IF(c>= 10000, "Tier 2",
IF(c<= 9999 , "Tier 1",
"")))))))
```